# define mongoose timestamps in schema

Tags: mongoose

There is a way to simply track the creation and update date of the documents without middlewares and extra code in POST/PUT queries?
Based on docs this should work, but if I try to update a document the updated_At field stays always equals to createdAt.

```
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{type:String},
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_At',updatedAt:'updated_At' }});
```

Comment: What is your mongoose version? I test your schema under mongoose v4.4.3, with `update` operation, the `updated_At` field could be updated correctly...

Comment: package.json:     "mongoose": "^4.4.2".
Should the update operations be done necessarily using PUT? my updates are currently POST in the form:
 `router.post('/:id', function(req,res,next) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(doc);
    });
});`